# ServletRequest getInputStream - read timed out

Tags: java, struts

Every once in a while, for the span of less than a second, I get read timeouts when trying to get the post data for a particular request. Its very strange to me that this would ever happen and I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before. This is happening in a public production web application, and happens at random times during the day about 8 instances a day (each instance lasting a second or less seeing anywhere from 1 to 15 read timeouts). Here's the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:751)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:781)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:710)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
    at com.offers.util.OffersHttpServletRequest.popuplateReqBytes(OffersHttpServletRequest.java:117)
    at com.offers.util.OffersHttpServletRequest.getPostData(OffersHttpServletRequest.java:64)
    at com.util.TrackAction.getPostData(TrackAction.java:148)
    ... 40 more
```

--- This confusion has been answered in the comments ---

Note that OffersHttpServletRequest is a class that overrides some methods (getPostData, getInputStream, isSecure, getReader, getRequestURL, getProtocol) - however popuplateReqBytes calls super.getInputStream() *not* the overridden getInputStream method. So I'm a little confused as to how the stack trace gets back into OffersHttpServletRequest.getInputStream from ServletRequestWrapper.getInputStream .

--- End confusion ---

--- Update ----

Changed stacktrace after making a change based off jtahlborn's observation. The change *didn't* solve the problem.

Comment: it looks like OffersHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper _and_ has an instance of this class passed as the delegate in the HttpServletRequestWrapper constructor...?

Comment: Very good eye. Thats exactly right. I didn't realize it, but there is a place in my code where I unnecessarily pass OffersHttpServletRequest another OffersHttpServletRequest request as a delgate. I don't believe thats causing the problem though. I'll make a change to prove that though, thanks.

Comment: So my change is in production, and I now get a more normal stack trace, but I'm still seeing this problem intermittently.

Comment: Given that your app is public-facing, this doesn't surprise me at all. You have no control over either the client (which may not actually be a web browser) or the quality of the majority of the network between your server and the client. Pretty much anything can and will happen. Now, if you can reproduce it under controlled circumstances on a local network, then you might have an issue.

Comment: So you're saying I should basically ignore this type of failure, since it is likely a badly formed request? If thats the case, write that up, and I'll accept that as an answer.